# does $unwind preserve indexes if array field has multi key index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

```
{
  A: [ { B: "number", C: "number" } ]
}
```

Supposed that there is a multi key index on `A`. Does the query below preserve that?

```
db.col.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$A" }, { $match: { } } ] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the indexes will **not** be preserved.

Indexes in `aggregate()` can only be used in the beginning of the pipeline, and not after the data has been transformed.

For example, you can leverage indexes with `$match` stage, if it's the first in the Aggregation pipeline. But if you put `$match` after the `$unwind`, it can not leverage the indexes since you already transformed the data.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that there is a multi key index on the unwind field? It is transformed, but the other is maintained.